# Is there anyone who has successfully published ios AppClip to your users on TestFlight env , or production env?

Tags: ios, testflight, ios14, apple-appclips

I developed an AppClip for ios 14.

It worked in my dev env, with Local Experience configured in ios developer menu setting.

But after I published it to test flight, there was no SmartAppBanner appear in safari.

Here my check list:

- [x] Configure the apple-app-site-association
- [x] Scan QR code to open AppClip successfully in dev mode
- [x] Scan QR code to open AppClip notice me: `This app was not available in your country` when I test the TestFlight
- [x] I've completed configure my AppClip  + experiences in AppStoreConnect for Testflight
- [x] The url prefix I've registered in TestFlight is: https://example.com/stock
- [x] Open my url: https://example.com in Safari, there is an SmartAppBanner show me the MainApp
- [x] Open my url: https://example.com/stock/VIC in Safari, there is `no` SmartAppBanner appears => Expectation: There must be an SmartAppBanner that show me "Open by in appclip" with `open` button
- [x] I've installed the AppClip (not the main app) from TestFlight, but after scanned the QR code, it shows me a blank AppClip Card with: "This app clip is not currently in your country or region

[image]

- [x] To get rid of "Not available in your country", I goto IOS setting > Developer > AppClip Setting > Register my local experiences ==> Then it can show my local AppClip Card  ===> I think Apple does not accept my appclips registration on TestFlight OR they do not allow my country (Vietnam) to use app clips?

I don't intend to publish my app to production if I cannot test it on Testflight.

Will publishing to production work?

Comment: You can publish the app in production, tested in the regular test flow. The App Clip will only appear if you activate it in App Store Connect AND someone get to webpage you have the Smart App Banner configured. If you did not publish this page, you can use it a a testbed

Comment: @LiazKamper what exactly do you mean by "activate it in App Store Connect"? Is there a button to click or something to activate it after the app released on the App Store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smart App Banner for App Clip appear **only** when the App and App Clip are *Ready For Sale* in the Store. In TestFlight you are able to test App Clip, but not the App Clip Card Experience.

Here is a relevant [thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663958) in Apple Support Forum:
This from directly from Apple staff:

> Safari's Smart App Banner and sharing via Messages is only available when the app clip is published in the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

Once you submit it to App Store Connect it will be available on TestFlight and appear as an app clip in your parent app to test.

Comment: Yes I've installed the AppClip (not the main app) from TestFlight, but after I scanned the QR code, it show me blank AppClip Card with: "This app clip is not currently in your country or region" :(

Comment: I afraid this is not correct. The app clip will appear in TestFlight in the context of the full App under the section *App Clips*